# I am struggling to update the BST file for Articel Style references

Tags: bibtex

I need to update the BST file for Article Style references for particular journals.

Hence my BST contains Volume Information's:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
}
```

And Article Function's:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ newline$
  "\bibtype{Article}%" write$
  output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      remove.dots
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.date "year" output.check
      date.block
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  format.endnote output
  format.commenturl output
  format.url output
  format.doi output
  format.eprint output
  fin.entry
}
```

My Bib File:

```
@article{Zamboni2009,
author = {P. Zamboni and R. Galeotti and E. Menegatti and A. M. Malagoni and G. Tacconi and S. Dall'ara and I. Bartolomei and F. Salvi},
title = {Chronic cerebrospinal venous insufficiency in patients with multiple sclerosis},
journal = {Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery and Psychiatry},
volume = {80},
number = {4},
pages = {392--399},
year = {2009},
doi = {10.1136/jnnp.2008.157164},
other = {2-s2.0-64749109556},
}
```

my Tex File:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}{Recursive Parameter Estimation}

\vspace{10pt}
{ Lawrence C. Sam}

\vspace{5pt}
{\small p.young@lancaster.ac.uk}
\end{center}

\section{Introduction}\label{intro}

The idea of sequentially.

\cite{Zamboni2009}
```

Getting Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Anyone suggested to solve this issue and it would be appreciated much more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) of compilable code that demonstrates your problem *and* say exactly what output you need/expect from the bst file.

Comment: @Andrew: I have edited my question as per your request.